# Windbg !heap -s and !heap -stat commands don't agree on output

Tags: windows, memory, windbg, unmanaged-memory

I have a memory dump. In this dump I have a heap with handle `fd00000`. This is an excerpt from the output of `!heap -s fd00000` command:

```
 0: Heap 0fd00000
 Flags          00001002 - HEAP_GROWABLE 
 Reserved memory in segments              80192 (k)
 Commited memory in segments              56540 (k)
 Virtual bytes (correction for large UCR) 60592 (k)
 Free space                               3884 (k) (572 blocks)
 External fragmentation          6% (572 free blocks)
 Virtual address fragmentation   6% (69 uncommited ranges)
 Virtual blocks  124 - total 0 KBytes
 Lock contention 23
 Segments        1
```

You see that it shows summary information as expected. But the ouptut of `!heap -stat -h 0fd00000`
shows the following:

```
 heap @ 0fd00000
 group-by: TOTSIZE max-display: 20
 size     #blocks     total     ( %) (percent of total busy bytes)
 19fa40 7a - c614280  (93.96)
 62d30 4 - 18b4c0  (0.73)
 d49 13d - 107365  (0.49)
```

It is all hexadecimal, so from here I see that "total busy bytes" exceed 205 MBytes. **So you see that `!heap -s` tells me that this heap has 80 MB/60 MB of Reserved/Virtual memory, while `!heap -stat` tells me that this heap occupies 205 MBytes.** The descrepancy is so huge. How this is possible? When I run `!heap -s` I see multiple entries like this:

```
Virtual block: 293c0000 - 293c0000 (size 00000000)
```

Maybe this is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some `!heap` switches are known to behave incorrectly when large allocations flow through the Heap Manager. The Heap Manager will forward large allocations directly to `VirtualAlloc`, and while some of the `!heap` commands know how to keep track of these allocations, other commands do not. You should also try updating your WinDbg version to the most recent Windows SDK, because the `!heap` commands are intimately tied to the Heap Manager's internal data structures, which change with Windows versions.

I recommend using VMMap in such situations to detect large allocation sources.